# Printing something continuously during no incoming request in Flask app

Tags: python, flask

I have a simple flask app where I need to print continuously **"no incoming request"** when there is no request incoming, to a particular route. Can anyone please help me to solve it

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say that you have to "print to a particular route"?

Comment: Suppose when there is no request incoming at root(/) then I want to print continuously on the console "no incoming request"

Comment: I am struggling with understanding the purpose of it, but I suppose there is one :) Why don't you print out something when you get a request and then assuming that if nothing is printed out there is "no incoming request"? :)

Comment: Basically I am connecting a flask app with a TCP incoming data via an endpoint. The request will be processed inside flask and then streamed to another server. So I need to send the remote server the request body if there is request incoming from TCP port and  "no incoming request" when there is no request or if the time difference between current time and last request time is more than 5 mins.

Comment: Can you make a [MCVE] of your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fun thing you want to achieve :). Here is a working script I put together. There will certainly be modifications to do to bend it to what it is you are seeking, but the general scheme seems sound to me.

```
from flask import Flask
import threading
import time

app = Flask(__name__)


class Printer(object):

    def __init__(self, time_to_sleep):
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.tts = time_to_sleep
        self.go_on = True

    def do_print(self):
        print "{}: no incoming requests".format(time.time())

    def loop(self):
        while self.go_on:
            time.sleep(self.tts)
            with self.lock:
                self.do_print()

    def exit(self):
        self.go_on = False


printer = Printer(1)


def lock_acquire(func):
    def __inner__(*args):
        with printer.lock:
            res = func(*args)
        return res
    return __inner__


@app.route('/')
@lock_acquire
def hello_world():
    time.sleep(5)
    return 'Hello, World!'


def run_app():
    host = "localhost"
    app.run(host=host, debug=1, use_reloader=False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = threading.Thread(target=printer.loop,
                     name="looper")
    t.start()
    run_app()
    printer.exit()
```

So you have one thread that periodically acquires a lock and prints a message. The route api endpoints are wrapped in a function that first acquire this lock (preventing the print thread from printing) and releases it when it is done. Another important thing is to add a control flow variable (go_on) in the loop in order not to keep the thread alive when exiting with Ctrl-C for example. Otherwise the script would hang, because the thread is not a daemon thread and will therefore keep the process alive.

Comment: Thank You Sir. Let me check it

Comment: Let me know :) I'm curious of any improvements you make so I learn as well.

Comment: Just added a few more stuff. [Here is the full code](https://github.com/Sayantanmukherjee6/Simple-Python-logger/blob/master/flask_test.py). Thanks a lot :)